# Cannot drag-select layers with Move tool in Photoshop when initially clicking in the canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

When using the Move tool, I can no longer drag-select layers when my cursor initially clicks on the canvas. However, if I initially click outside of the canvas I can drag-select towards the canvas, a rectangular marquee will appear, and the border to that rectangle successfully selects the layers it touches.

But, when I open a new document I can drag-select with the Move tool no problem.

Any ideas on what's going on?  I reset all my tools, restarted Photoshop, and my computer.  Still no dice

Comment: some times the letter "Q" gets press and puts it in Quick-mask mode which could effect this.

Answer (score 2):

check auto-select box as shown below

[image]

Comment: Hi Ali TEK - etulia.com, Welcome to GDSE! Could you please elaborate a bit more on your answer and what we'll find behind the link you provided and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you mistakenly pressed "Q" key and the page converts into Quick Mask mode. and while dragging any layer on the canvas, you will see red border dragged through.

Make sure that you haven't pressed Q.

Another thing is if in case you have unchecked Auto Select, that works on layers. then also you can not drag the layers.

[image]