# When using artboards in Photoshop, I can't drag-select layers—the artboard gets selected

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

On a regular file (not using artboards), I can usually drag select layers as needed with the Move tool. But when using artboards, if I try to do the same thing, the whole artboard gets selected, even if I drag within the bounds of the artboard, not touching the artboard edge.

There's no way to lock the artboard without locking the layers within. Any ideas?

This issue seems different from the one discussed here: [Cannot drag-select layers with Move tool in Photoshop when initially clicking in the canvas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41008/cannot-drag-select-layers-with-move-tool-in-photoshop-when-initially-clicking-in)

Comment: do you even need that artboard? you can use the Un-Group option on the artboard layer to "delete" it

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I did some research and answered my own problem.. On the layers select the art board and then lock the position using the icon that is a cross hair with two double sided arrows. Locking the layer it won't work the same :)

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show what you mean.